# Can we set "-fno-jump-tables" as “Other Cflags” in XCode?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

Is there a way to set "-fno-jump-tables" as “Other Cflags” in XCode. I tried setting it but it gives compilation error. The error reads something like this "i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: fno-jump-tables: No such file or directory".

I am using gcc version 4.2. Mac OS X 10.6.8. Xcode version is 3.2.6.

Regards,
Vishvesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me from the command line.

```
gcc -fno-jump-tables foo.c
```

From the error, it looks like the leading `-` is getting lost and `fno-jump-tables` is being treated as a file. I assume you are putting `-fno-jump-tables` in "other C flags" and not just `fno-jump-tables`

Comment: I tried both "fno-jump-tables" and "-fno-jump-tables". The results were the same.